AntDesign Pro build deployment cannot log in Response status: 404
After the project is built and deployed, I cannot log in. I can log in normally using yarn start or npm run start locally. I cannot log in after deployment, Response status:404 .
URL: http://localhost:8000/api/login/account?token%20=%20123
: POST
: 404 Not Found

vision：ant-design-pro@6.0.0
deployment node run_server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

// 使用path.join获取绝对路径
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on http://localhost:${port}`);
});


proxy.ts
export default {
  test: {
    // localhost:8000/api/** -> https://preview.pro.ant.design/api/**
    '/api/': {
      target: 'https://proapi.azurewebsites.net',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: { '^': '' },
    },
  },
  pre: {
    '/api/': {
      target: 'your pre url',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: { '^': '' },
    },
  },
};


config.ts
// https://umijs.org/config/
import { defineConfig } from '@umijs/max';
import { join } from 'path';
import defaultSettings from './defaultSettings';
import proxy from './proxy';
import routes from './routes';
const { REACT_APP_ENV = 'dev' } = process.env;
export default defineConfig({
  history: { type: 'hash' }, // 默认是 browser
  hash: true,
  routes,
  theme: {
    // 如果不想要 configProvide 动态设置主题需要把这个设置为 default
    // 只有设置为 variable， 才能使用 configProvide 动态设置主色调
    'root-entry-name': 'variable',
  },
  ignoreMomentLocale: true,
  proxy: proxy[REACT_APP_ENV as keyof typeof proxy],
  fastRefresh: true,
  model: {},
  initialState: {},

  title: 'AntDesign',
  layout: {
    locale: true,
    ...defaultSettings,
  },

  moment2dayjs: {
    preset: 'antd',
    plugins: ['duration'],
  },

  antd: {},

  request: {},

  access: {},

  headScripts: [
    // 解决首次加载时白屏的问题
    {
      src: '/scripts/loading.js',
      async: true,
    },
  ],
  ……
});

It doesn't work.
After the project is built and deployed, I cannot log in. I can log in normally using yarn start or npm run start locally. I cannot log in after deployment, Response status:404 .
